Quiero solucionar el error 403 en mi sistema de autenticacion
Tengo el error 403 al usar postman al hacer un get o post aunque uso mi bearer token que me genera al logearme con un usuario que lo logre meter antes de ingresar el sistema de seguridad y mi usuario en la base de datos tiene el rol de administrador.
Probé usando .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/users/**").hasRole("ADMIN") y .hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"), en mi base de datos está escrito como ROLE_ADMIN.
Sin embargo al ingresar el token que me genera y querer hacer un post o un get me da el error 403, al usar el token en otra api que está conectado a este sistema normal me deja usar post o get usando el bearer token con el rol de admin
SecurityConfig.java:
package authserver.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthorizationFilter jwtAuthorizationFilter;

    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception{
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Configurando SecurityFilterChain...");
        return http.authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth
                .requestMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-ui/index.html").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/users/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/users/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/roles/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/roles/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .addFilter(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthorizationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .csrf(config -> config.disable())
                .sessionManagement(management -> management.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .build();
    }
    
}

JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:

package authserver.config;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.crypto.SecretKey;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.exc.StreamReadException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;
import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import pe.idat.dsi.dcn.authserver.models.User;

public class JwtAuthenticationFilter  extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter{
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private static final SecretKey SECRET_KEY = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor("RXdKSps6tFLqkWgdIKGs4EFo696TnYjn7mR+6s+dSHo=".getBytes());//Jwts.SIG.HS256.key().build();
    private static final String PREFIX_TOKEN = "Bearer ";
    private static final String HEADER_AUTHORIZATION = "Authorization";

    public JwtAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        User user = null;
        String username = null; 
        String password = null;
        try {
            user = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), User.class);
            username = user.getUsername();
            password = user.getPassword();
        } catch (StreamReadException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DatabindException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);

        return this.authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,
            Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User user = (org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User) authResult.getPrincipal();
        String username = user.getUsername();

        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> roles = authResult.getAuthorities();
        List<String> rolesList = roles.stream()
                .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        Claims claims = Jwts.claims();
        claims.put("authorities", rolesList);
        claims.put("username", username);


        String jws = Jwts.builder()
            .setSubject(username)
            .setClaims(claims)
            .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 3600000)) //1 hora
            .setIssuedAt(new Date())
            .signWith(SECRET_KEY)
            .compact();

        response.addHeader(HEADER_AUTHORIZATION, PREFIX_TOKEN + jws);
        Map<String, String> body = Map.of("token", jws, "username", username, "message", String.format("Hola %s has iniciado sesión con éxito", username));
        response.getWriter().write(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(body));
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setStatus(200);
    }

    @Override
    protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException, ServletException {
                Map<String, String> body = Map.of("message", "Error en la autenticación: Usuario y/o clave incorrectos", "error", failed.getMessage());
                response.getWriter().write(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(body));
                response.setContentType("application/json");
                response.setStatus(401);


    }

    

    
}


JwtAuthorizationFilter.java:
package authserver.config;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.crypto.SecretKey;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;
import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@Component
public class JwtAuthorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private static final SecretKey SECRET_KEY = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor("RXdKSps6tFLqkWgdIKGs4EFo696TnYjn7mR+6s+dSHo=".getBytes());

    private static final String PREFIX_TOKEN = "Bearer ";
    private static final String HEADER_AUTHORIZATION = "Authorization";

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String header = request.getHeader(HEADER_AUTHORIZATION);

        if (!StringUtils.hasText(header) || !header.startsWith(PREFIX_TOKEN)) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        String token = header.replace(PREFIX_TOKEN, "");
        try {
            Claims claims = Jwts.parserBuilder()
                                .setSigningKey(SECRET_KEY)
                                .build()
                                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                                .getBody();
        
            String username = claims.getSubject();
            System.out.println("Username extraído del token: " + username);
        
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<String> authoritiesList = (List<String>) claims.get("authorities");

            List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = authoritiesList.stream()
                    .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
            if (username != null) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication =
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null, authorities);
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
                System.out.println("Autenticación establecida en SecurityContext: " + SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());
            }
        
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: Token expirado");
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            response.getWriter().write("Token expirado");
            return;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: Token inválido");
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            response.getWriter().write("Token inválido");
            return;
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        System.out.println("Después de chain.doFilter: " + SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());
    }

}

